# In memory table and temp table in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am looking for Sql-Server relevant feature in MySql

Table variable inside procedure. [here](http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx)

Temporary Table inside procedure. [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42553/Quick-Overview-Temporary-Tables-in-SQL-Server)

I hope the table variables are in-memory and temporary tables are stored in temp database.
If both declared inside procedure, both will be cleaned after the procedure finished its execution.

MySql provides only one option called Temporary Table. How to achieve these two? and do we need to clear those tables or MySql will take care of it after the procedure completed?

Answer (score 2):

From MySQL documentation:

> You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a table. A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current session, and is dropped automatically when the session is closed. This means that two different sessions can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY table of the same name. 
>   More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html#create-temporary-table

But what happens if I'm using a single connection? May be you will have some data conflicts. In the past I use temporary tables with a unique id to avoid conflicts if I call the procedure with the same connection more than one time:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE some_proc $$
CREATE PROCEDURE some_proc () 
BEGIN

    -- creating a unique value
    DECLARE VARIABLE tmp_uuid varchar(50);
    SET tmp_uuid = uuid();


    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_temporary
    (
        uuid_id varchar(50), 
        col1 varchar(10),
        col2 varchar(10),
        INDEX(uuid_id)
    );

   -- do some operations on that

    INSERT INTO tbl_temporary(uuid_id, ...) VALUES (tmp_uuid,...);


    -- now, cleaning the data
    DELETE FROM tbl_temporary WHERE uuid_id = tmp_uuid;

    -- if the current session is closed the table will be automatically deleted
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```